# meaning of some lines in a book

Tags: linear-algebra

Would you please anyone translate these three lines into a simpler meaning? it's written in very advanced level.

[image]

Comment: If you don't understand, you might be better asking at math.stackoverflow.com which answers mathematics questions. Translating or paraphrasing technical material requires technical expertise to know the precise terminology.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about domain-specific technical text that would be completely opaque to the average native Anglophone

Comment: @Fumblefingers I too thought about closing it but then realised that the detail of the maths is irrelevant. PO is asking about the meaning of "means" in a mathematical context, which seems valid territory for us to explore because even mathematicians use and need English to explain themselves.

Comment: @Anton: oic. Perhaps someone with better graphics editing skills than me could add a big red circle round that word in *has a zero **mean*** (not *This **means**!* :) in the question, to make that crystal clear. Also, I can't speak for specialists in this domain, but to me as an "ordinary" native speaker, I'd infinitely prefer ***is independent of*** over ***does not co-vary with*** - which latter just strikes me as gratuitous geek-speak here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers OK, if it’s about maths it is off topic and if it is about English it has too much maths in it and lacks clarity. Let’s close it for lack of clarity?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about domain-specific technical text that would be completely opaque to the average native Anglophone

Comment: I retracted my closevote, but the truth is I *really* wasn't paying attention. I thought I was looking at this question on [English Language **Learners**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where I wouldn't say it's necessarily unreasonable for a querent to ask about this particular meaning of ***mean*** (especially given the context *also* includes the same word as a verb, with a completely different sense). Whatever - I can't closevote again (only upvote @MichaelHarvey's closevote), but here on ELU I think it's just "too basic" (lacks adequate "prior research").

Comment: You have convinced me. I shall be your proxy.

Comment: I think all of these comments are a bit off. The OP asked for the meaning of the three lines, not of '(this) means'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'covariance' is a very common concept and term in statistics and related fields. But you're right that a covariance of 0 is equivalent to saying that two variables are independent, so if the audience were laypeople it would be better.

Comment: What does your research show you regarding the meanings of the words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prediction error has a zero mean: some predicted values will be too high, and some will be too low. The mean of these errors will be 0.

The prediction error does not co-vary with any linear function of the inputs: It doesn't matter if some predictor variable has a very low or a a very high value, the error in the outcome variable will not be systematically affected. It also doesn't matter if some *combination* of predictor variables (for example, x_1 * x_2) has a very low or a very high value, the error will not be affected.

These are basic assumptions in much statistical modelling. If a high value of a predictor gives you bigger prediction error, you have a problem with your model (usually). So these lines are basically just saying "we did our modelling properly".

Comment: No. Where did I say that?

Answer (score 4):

The mathematics itself is a "red herring". Regardless of the details of the mathematical argument, "*means ...*" in this mathematical context is used in the sense of "*implies that ...*", "*shows that*" or "*leads to the logical conclusion that ...*"

> mean = to have a particular result
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mean)

> mean = to serve or intend to convey, show, or indicate
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mean)

In response to comment and query I add that the full meaning cannot be reliably given, although there are hints of meaning everywhere in the quotation.

The quote is clearly about the linear regression (y = w0 + w1 x) of a set of n values (xi, yi). J is a function of these values and of the two parameters w0 (intercept) and w1 (slope).

A linear combination of two variables is merely the sum of them when each is numerically multiplied in some way (perhaps with the addition of a constant number, or not). If they are A and B, for example, a linear combination would be (3A +2.89B). (2A + 5B + AB) is not linear because A and B are multiplied together. Nor is (A squared).

If something co-varies with something else, it means that if you change one, the other changes. If this is not the case, they do not covary. The two partial differential equations ( ... =0) show that J does not change if you change w0 or w1. (*This likely follows from the maths, because w0 and w1 are chosen by calculating from the n values of (xi, yi)*). Hence J does not covary with w0 or w1. It is not clear how this argument finishes.

A full and reliable meaning cannot be given without further information because the mathematical part of the quotation is incomplete in three respects: the function J is not defined other than by its partial derivatives; the significance of the * is not given; *w* is not defined. All other symbols (including the x with a bar over it, representing the mean value of x) are conventional and understandable.

I hope this helps understand the English that is used in such technical ways. I could do better but that would lead in to a mathematical explanation rather than discussing the use of English.

Comment: Although the red line points to the word "means," the OP is asking about the paragraph ("these three lines").

Comment: Yes, but we answer questions about English here, not about Mathematics, despite its fascination.

Comment: I have edited my answer to help you.

Comment: You mean it's a mean mean?