# Regression error function minimization problem

Tags: optimization, regression, error-function

[image: Click here to view the problem]

Could somebody please help with this problem. There is a little explanation in this link:
[meaning of some lines in a book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946099/meaning-of-some-lines-in-a-book/3946102#3946102)

But it is still a bit ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

For easier notation, let $J(u,v) = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-u-vx_i)^2$ and let $(u^*,v^*)$ denote the values at which $J$ achieves its minimum. Then, since $J$ is smooth, from calculus we know that
$$
\left. \frac{\partial J}{\partial u} \right|_{u = u^*,v = v^*}
= 0 =
\left. \frac{\partial J}{\partial v} \right|_{u = u^*,v = v^*}
$$
Can you find both partial derivatives?

Comment: I can find partial derivatives. I don't see why the prediction error does not covary with any linear function of the inputs.